# Python webhook called multiple times from Facebook Chatbot - Api.ai

Tags: python-2.7, dialogflow-es, facebook-webhooks

I am developing a fb chatbot where for specific intents, webhooks are been fired and process via python. The python app is hosted in Heroku cloud. I'm facing a typical problem, whenever any webhook is been fired, it keeps continued to be fired in an infinite loop until the next query from chat is been triggered.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import os
import psycopg2
import urlparse

from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template
from flask import make_response


# Flask should start in global layout
context = Flask(__name__)

# Webhook requests are coming to this method
@context.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    reqContext = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    if reqContext.get("result").get("action") == "input.welcome":
       return welcome()
    elif reqContext.get("result").get("action") == "yahooWeatherForecast":
       return weatherhook(reqContext)
    elif reqContext.get("result").get("action") == "GoogleSearch":
       return searchhook()
    else:
       print("Good Bye")
```

I have enabled webhook for 3 intents only. Other intents in api.ai does not have fulfillment (Webhook or Webhook slot filling) enabled.

Can anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to look for in such case:

1. We need to send response 200 to facebook to end the response
2. Need to check whether the message delivery response is enabled on the fb subscription or not. If it is enabled, fb will send delivery response as well, which should be caught on webhook.